# WordPress po mo file

Tags: php, wordpress, translation, po, mo

Hi all I have one problem. Po file doesn't work. I use qtransltae-x for translation. And I create custom pot file

example

```
# Copyright (C) 2015 Gawatt
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: Gawatt 1.0.0\n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2015-06-03 11:30+0400\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: 2015-MO-DA HO:MI+ZONE\n"
"Last-Translator: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>\n"
"Language-Team: LANGUAGE <LL@li.org>\n"
"X-Generator: Poedit 1.8.1\n"

#: club.php:25
msgid "zibil"
msgstr ""
```

after that I generate it`

```
# Copyright (C) 2015 Gawatt
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: Gawatt 1.0.0\n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2015-06-03 11:30+0400\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: 2015-06-03 12:45+0400\n"
"X-Generator: Poedit 1.7.6\n"
"Last-Translator: \n"
"Language-Team: \n"
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=3; plural=(n%10==1 && n%100!=11 ? 0 : n%10>=2 && n%10<=4 && (n%100<10 || n%100>=20) ? 1 : 2);\n"
"Language: ru_RU\n"

#: club.php:25
msgid "zibil"
msgstr "sdfsdfsdfsdf"
```

code output `

```
<?php _e('zibil'); ?>
```

and in wp-config

```
define('WPLANG', 'ru_RU');
```

but when I switch language to russina it doesn't work, can you please help me thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to translate your theme you need to tell Wordpress where to find the translation files using: `<?php load_theme_textdomain( $domain, $path ) ?>`, [doc](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/load_theme_textdomain).

For example:

```
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'my_theme_setup');
function my_theme_setup(){
    load_theme_textdomain('my_theme', get_template_directory() . '/languages');
}
```

And when using the function `_e()` you have to include the domain, [doc](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_e)

Like so: `<?php _e('zibil', 'mytheme'); ?>`.